# When does $\left(\prod_{i=1}^nA_i\right)' \not\subseteq \prod_{i=1}^n A_i'$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I do know that $\prod_{i=1}^n A_i' \subseteq \left(\prod_{i=1}^n A_i\right)'$, as my (brief) material only shows the implication one way, I'm presuming that the converse is not always true. What would be an example of this?

$A'$ means the set of accumulation points of the set $A$.

Comment: By $A'$ do you mean the topological closure?

Comment: @blamethelag By $A'$ I mean the set of accumulation points of the set $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $n = 2$, $A_1 = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$ and $A_2 = [0,2]$ with the standard topology of $\mathbb R$. Then
$$
(A_1 \times A_2)' = A_1 \times A_2 \neq [0,1] \times [0,2] = A_1' \times A_2'.
$$